# Need clarification on Independent Events Probability question

Tags: probability

*In the World Series of baseball, two teams A and B play a sequence of games against each other, and the first team that wins a total of four games becomes the winner
of the World Series. If the probability that team A will win any particular game against team B is 1/3, what is the probability that team A will win the World Series?*

I can solve this easily my way, by summing the probabilities of winning on the 4th, 5th, 6th, and 7th game. My textbook offers a different solution and I'm trying to understand why it works. They say that

$\sum \matrix{7 \\ i=4} \pmatrix{7 \\ i} \left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\right)^i \left(\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}\right)^{7-i} $

Would anyone kindly explain why that is a valid approach?

Comment: If you would show us your way, Franky, we might be able to explain you if and why it is wrong.

Comment: $\sum \matrix{6 \\ i=3} \pmatrix{i \\ 3} \left(\frac {1}{3} \right)^{4} \left(\frac {2}{3} \right)^{i-3} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be formulated as the equivalent one:

Team A wins the majority of 7 games

Thus, you compute the probability of winning 4, 5, 6 or 7 games out of 7. This yields the desired result.

Comment: This is the closest to the explanation I'm looking for. It still seems like an odd way of looking at to me. Perhaps I haven't enough experience to "feel" this answer as being equivalent without running the numbers to double check.

Comment: It's not an obvious answer. But if team A wins the world series it means they've won 4 games and hence the majority of 7 games played. Conversely, if team A wins the majority of the 7 games then it has to have at least 4 victories and team B has a maximum of 3 .

Comment: OK. I'm still shaky on it, intuitively it just doesn't feel right but then many things in probability seem to work against intuition. However, I don't doubt that it's correct. Your explanation was very helpful. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a probability guru, but here is how I would read the solution:

Given two independent events, A and B, the probability of A happening is $P(A)$ and the probability of B happening is $P(B)$.

- The probability of A happening **and** B happening is $ P(A) \times P(B) $.
- The probability of B happening **or** B happening is $ P(A) + P(B) $.

$ \frac{1}{3} $ is the probability of winning a single game by itself.

$ \frac{2}{3} $ is the probability of loosing a single game by itself.

$ 7 \choose i $ (read as "7 choose i") is the number of ways $ i $ games could be won, out of 7 games played.  For example, $ 7 \choose 7 $ must be $ \{ win, win, win, win, win, win, win \} $.  $ 7 \choose 1 $ could be $ \{ win, loss, loss, loss, loss, loss, loss \} $ or $ \{ loss, win, loss, loss, loss, loss, loss \} $, etc.

The summation creates a string of **or** operations. Also, the $ 7 \choose i $ creates a similar string of **or** operations.

$ (\frac{1}{3})^i $ is the probability of winning $ i $ games.

$ (\frac{2}{3})^{7-i} $ is the probability of losing $ 7 - i $ games.

Therefore, $ (\frac{1}{3})^i (\frac{2}{3})^{7-i} $ is the probability of winning $ i $ games **and** losing $ 7 - i $ games.

Given the $ 7 \choose i $, the expression $ {7 \choose i} (\frac{1}{3})^i (\frac{2}{3})^{7-i} $ is the probability of winning some and losing some in one combination, **or** winning some and losing some in another combination, etc.

Going through the summation, we have:

- $ i = 4 $ means the probability of winning 4 games and losing 3 games.
- $ i = 5 $ means the probability of winning 5 games and losing 2 games.
- $ i = 6 $ means the probability of winning 6 games and losing 1 games.
- $ i = 7 $ means the probability of winning 7 games and losing 0 games.

Remember, the $ 7 \choose i $ creates an **or** condition across all win/loss combinations.  All combined, the expressions cover any possible win/loss conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach, as well as the textbook's approach, are equally valid. Here's how.

I'll just reframe the question to save some space and to avoid complexity but still maintaining the nature of the problem.

Suppose instead of 4, the winner is declared as soon as any team wins 3 games.

Let $p=\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}$ and $q=\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}$ such that $p+q=1$

Let W denote that team A wins a game and L denote that team A loses a game.
Following are the scenarios where team A wins (It's not very hard to figure out that playing 5 games are enough in any tournament to find a winning team).

Possible tournaments where A wins exactly 3 games ($\pmatrix{5 \\ 3}$ = 10 tournaments)

1. W,W,**W**,L,L
2. W,W,L,**W**,L
3. W,W,L,L,**W**
4. W,L,W,**W**,L
5. W,L,W,L,**W**
6. W,L,L,W,**W**
7. L,W,W,**W**,L
8. L,W,W,L,**W**
9. L,W,L,W,**W**
10. L,L,W,W,**W**

Possible tournaments where A wins exactly 4 games ($\pmatrix{5 \\ 4}$ = 5 tournaments)

11. W,W,**W**,W,L
12. W,W,**W**,L,W
13. W,W,L,**W**,W
14. W,L,W,**W**,W
15. L,W,W,**W**,W

Possible tournaments where A wins exactly 5 games ($\pmatrix{5 \\ 5}$ = 1 tournament)

16. W,W,**W**,W,W

The list mentioned above is the textbook's approach.

P(team A winning) = $\sum \matrix{5 \\ i=3} \pmatrix{5 \\ i} p^i * q^{5-i}$

Notice the bold **W**? Well, that is your approach. The bold **W** means that you are not considering the outputs after **W** (or, the teams don't play once team A wins 3 out of 5 games).

To see how it is equivalent, we'll rearrange the 3 lists into another set of lists (preserving the order number).

Team A winning on the 3rd game

1. W,W,**W**,<s>L,L</s>

11. W,W,**W**,<s>W,L</s>

12. W,W,**W**,<s>L,W</s>

16. W,W,**W**,<s>W,W</s>

Team A winning on the 4th game

2. W,W,L,**W**,<s>L</s>

13. W,W,L,**W**,<s>W</s>

4. W,L,W,**W**,<s>L</s>

14. W,L,W,**W**,<s>W</s>

7. L,W,W,**W**,<s>L</s>

15. L,W,W,**W**,<s>W</s>

Team A winning on the 5th game

3. W,W,L,L,**W**

5. W,L,W,L,**W**

6. W,L,L,W,**W**

8. L,W,W,L,**W**

9. L,W,L,W,**W**

10. L,L,W,W,**W**

Let's calculate the probability when team A is winning on the **3rd game** (This event occurs when either of 1, 11, 12 or 16 occurs).
P(team A winning on 3rd game) = $p^{3}*q*q+p^{3}*p*q+p^{3}*q*p+p^{3}*p*p$

P(team A winning on 3rd game) = $p^{3}*[q^{2}+2pq+p^{2}]$

P(team A winning on 3rd game) = $p^{3}$

*The intuition here is that once team A has won on the 3rd game, the result of the remaining two games does not change the outcome of team A winning the tournament. Imagine telling the players to continue playing the games even after the match has been decided, just for fun.*

Similarly, team A winning on **4th game** happens when either of 2, 13, 4, 14, 7 or 15 occurs

P(team A winning on 4th game) = $p^{2}*q*p*[p+q] + p^{2}*q*p*[p+q] + p*q*p^{2}*[p+q]$

P(team A winning on 4th game) = $3*p^{3}*q$

*Once team A has won on the 4th game, the result of the remaining game does not change the outcome of team A winning the tournament. Imagine telling the players to continue playing the game even after the match has been decided, just for fun.*

On the same line, team A winning on **5th game** happens when either of 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 or 10 occurs
P(team A winning on 5th game) = $6*p^{3}*q^{2}$

This gives: P(team A winning) = $p^{3} + 3 * p^{3}*q + 6*p^{3}*q^{2}$; which is equivalent to the formula derived using your approach, i.e.,

P(team A winning) = $\sum \matrix{4 \\ i=2} \pmatrix{i \\ 2} p^{3} * q^{i-2}$

*Takeaway here is that there is no harm in teams playing all the 5 games (or even more number of games) once the winner is declared in the first 3 or 4 or 5 games because, for example, P(Team A will win the tournament by playing n more games | Team A has already won first 3 games) = 1*

***For more clarification refer to section 4 on page no. 9 [here](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_3.pdf).***

Comment: Why revive this, which has an accepted answer for 2.5 years? Surely tons of more recent questions are in want of your expertise...

Comment: @Did I believe it's too late too. ***OK. I'm still shaky on it, intuitively it just doesn't feel right but then many things in probability seem to work against intuition.*** It's this statement by the OP that urged me to write an explanation. Also, this is a common problem where learners get stuck in understanding the two approaches. The approaches are extensively used in several problems indirectly.